# Unity: object with strange transparent color?

Tags: unity

In my game the players left arm is this weird transparent color, but the right is normal. When i drag the right arm's material over to the left it doesn't fix the problem, so there's something wrong with the object itself not the material. How do i fix this?
[image]

Comment: anyone...? I need help.

Comment: I guess we can't help with this much info. Which components did you used to build arms and what's the difference in both arms ? may be light effects etc ?

Comment: both have exactly the same components, settings and materials.

Answer (score 2):

3D models are usually rendered only on the outside or inside of the model, the reason the right arm is partially transparent is probably because during the 3d modelling process the right arm had its faces flipped so that when rendered in unity the arms inside faces are the only faces that render hence the reason you can see the back and not the front. I know in particular blender renders both sides which can confuse people when they import their models into unity and see only one side of the face rendered.

I don't know what 3d modelling software you use but if you look online you should find a tutorial on how to invert the drawn faces, this may solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like inverted normals. There are several modelling packages that invert normals when doing a mirroring-operation, so that might be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem behind this, but one possible solution is to import your right hand in Google SketchUp and make its mirror image model. Then export its .fbx file and include this .fbx file to your unity project. It should work.